# How to inverse addSearchCondition in yii1.1?

Tags: php, yii

I want to create a query which boils to a

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE property IS NOT LIKE "%FOOBAR%"
```

Apparently, for a like condition one can use:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addSearchCondition('property', 'FOOBAR');
$result = Table::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Yet how do I inverse that criteria?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 5th parameter of [addSearchCondition()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail):

```php
$criteria->addSearchCondition('property', 'FOOBAR', true, 'AND', 'NOT LIKE');
```

Comment: Can one also indicate the left and right side of the like? `%FOOBAR%` vs `%FOOBAR` vs `FOOBAR%`?

Comment: You can use `$criteria->addSearchCondition('property', 'FOOBAR%', false, 'AND', 'NOT LIKE');`, but you need to [escape](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/0d9af3802fbd1d6a532f3c0d8e6307625e0baab5/framework/db/schema/CDbCriteria.php#L256) wildcards manually (so searching "FOO%BAR" will result `FOO\%BAR%` in query).